# EmguCV in Unity 5. Problems with dll-files

Tags: .net, dll, unity-game-engine, emgucv

I have a problem with EmguCV in Unity 5. I followed the instructions of other Threads and copied the EmguCV dlls in the Plugin-folder and do some more steps.

When I'm running a small test program where I use EmguCV everything is ok. But when I try to get my own EmguCV project running into Unity there are a lot of errors because of missing .dll files or because it is not able to load some classes.

For example it has problems with the PresentationCore. If I add the Assembly to the PresentationCore in Visual Studio it still don't know the classes I'm using out of the PresentationCore.

I've copied the `PresentationCore.dll` into the Plugin folder of my Unity project. Now it can compile the Scripts but running the program I get Errors like these:

> SpritePacker failed to get types from PresentationCore,
>   Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35. 
>   Error: The classes in the module cannot be loaded.
>   UnityEditor.Sprites.Packer:GetSelectedPolicyId()
>
> DllNotFoundException: MSVCR80.dll .?A0xe96b2b07.clock_wrapper
>   ()
>
> TypeLoadException: A type load exception has occurred.
>
> DllNotFoundException: wpfgfx_v0300.dll
>   System.Windows.Media.FactoryMaker..ctor ()
>
> FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'UIAutomationTypes, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies.

Has anyone here had similar problems and knows how to solve them? Or any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem that is solved by attaching my script to the target in-game object (`Add Component`). When it is removed, it leads to a very similar error message whenever I try to run Unity.